# Is there a way to Connect a function ''normally'' through its Pole?

Tags: plotting, functions, mathematical-optimization

Basicaly I have this function:

```
Vff[x] = (1.33872 (-x^2 + 
     x^2 (0.0337677 + 3.53187 x - 8.1484 x^2 + 12.6818 x^3 - 
        12.3699 x^4 + 7.65446 x^5 - 3.04756 x^6 + 0.777227 x^7 - 
        0.122575 x^8 + 0.010878 x^9 - 0.00041522 x^10)))/(x (-1 + 
     x^2 (0.0337677 + 3.53187 x - 8.1484 x^2 + 12.6818 x^3 - 
        12.3699 x^4 + 7.65446 x^5 - 3.04756 x^6 + 0.777227 x^7 - 
        0.122575 x^8 + 0.010878 x^9 - 0.00041522 x^10)))
```

One can do the plot:

```
Plot[Vff[x], {x, 0, 5}, PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Blue}}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

To get this image:

[image]

Is there any way to find the function of this and somehow make it  pas through (1,0.2)  normally?

Any help is appreciated :)

EDIT: (Progress?)

I have made two lists, one for x<0.85 and one for x>1.15 and after merging them:

```
Leftt = Table[{x, N[Vff[x]]}, {x, 0.01, 0.85, .2}];
Rightt = Table[{x, N[Vff[x]]}, {x, 1.15, 5, .2}];
VFF = Riffle[Leftt, Rightt];
```

[image]

I tried to FindFormula, resulating in a constant 0.154???

```
VFFF[x_] = 
 FindFormula[VFF, x, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
  SpecificityGoal -> "Low"]
VFFF[x]
0.154565
```

Edit2: Fixed it!! Just made the analysis better!

Comment: Depends on what you mean by Normal. You can try the option Exclusions -> None which will remove the disconnect. However the pole will still be there. If you want to remove the pole completely then create a Table of values for x and Vff[x] with x=1 removed. Then ListPlot this data.

Comment: @Lotus Hmm will try to find this way with table. don't know how to do it(new to mathematica) Thanks for your Help!

Comment: @billy isn't that more of a math problem? We can help implement any solution/algorithm you find but it is rather broad now, e.g. you can draw a straight line from `{.5 Vff[.5]}` to `{1.5, Vff[1.5]}` and it fits description.

Comment: @kuba I just didn't know if there was anycommand like (Flatten) or stuf like this that would bypass this pole.

Comment: @Lotus   I have tried this maybe if you have any tip ? :(

Comment: @Kuba Didn't let my tag you on the previous comment. Just seeking your help again :)

Comment: Looks like `Vff` could be a Padé approximation and you're trying to use it outside its range of validity. It may be better to go back to the origin of the approximation from which `Vff` is derived, and choose different parameters there.